# Replacing 'source file' with its content, and expanding variables, in bash

Tags: bash, set, expansion, subshell

In a script.sh,

```
source a.sh
source b.sh

CMD1
CMD2
CMD3
```

how can I replace the `source *.sh` with their content (without executing the commands)?
I would like to see what the bash interpreter executes after sourcing the files and expanding all variables.

I know I can use `set -n -v` or run `bash -n -v script.sh 2>output.sh`, but that would not replace the source commands (and even less if a.sh or b.sh contain variables).

I thought of using a subshell, but that still doesn't expand the source lines. I tried a combination of `set +n +v` and `set -n -v` before and after the source lines, but that still does not work.

I'm going to send that output to a remote machine using ssh.
I could use `<<output.sh` to pipe the content into the ssh command, but I can't log as root onto the remote machine, but I am however a sudoer.
Therefore, I thought I could create the script and send it as a base64-encoded string (using [that clever trick](https://serverfault.com/questions/625641/how-can-i-run-arbitrarily-complex-command-using-sudo-over-ssh) )
`base64 script | ssh remotehost 'base64 -d | sudo bash'`

Is there a solution?
Or do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

inline.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ (\.|source)\s+.+ ]]; then
        file="$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)"
        echo "$(cat $file)"
    else
      echo "$line"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

Note this assumes the `source`d files exist, and doesn't handle errors. You should also handle possible hashbangs. If the `sourced` files contain themselves `source`, you need to apply the script recursively, e.g. something like (not tested):

```
while egrep -q '^(source|\.)' main.sh; do
    bash inline.sh main.sh > main.sh
done
```

Let's test it

main.sh:

```
source a.sh
. b.sh

echo cc
echo "$var_a $var_b"
```

a.sh:

```
echo aa
var_a="stack"
```

b.sh:

```
echo bb
var_b="overflow"
```

Result:

```
bash inline.sh main.sh

echo aa
var_a="stack"
echo bb
var_b="overflow"

echo cc
echo "$var_a $var_b"

bash inline.sh main.sh | bash

aa
bb
cc
stack overflow
```

BTW, if you just want to see what bash executes, you can run

```
bash -x [script]
```

or remotely

```
ssh user@host -t "bash -x [script]"
```

Comment: Have you tried your solution, when a.sh defines a variable, and main.sh calls it after 'echo cc'?
I don't think that variable gets expanded.
And yes, I know already about the -x.
The script is meant to run on the remote machine, not mine, but I want to write it programmatically (ie with variables and some sort of includes)

Comment: Updated the answer. The value doesn't need to be expanded, we just need its definition to be inlined (unless the sourced files contain themselves `source`). Why is there a difference between remote and local in this case? E.g. you can use `ssh user@host -t "bash -x -c 'echo hi'"`

Comment: I wrote an improved version that supports indentation and sourcing sources: https://gist.github.com/joehillen/30f08738c1c3c0ca3e4c754ad33ad2ff

Comment: For anyone who is struggling with this, I've developed a POSIX script that is compatible with ShellCheck and completely customizable: https://github.com/carlocorradini/inline