# How to merge "sourced" bash scripts to single bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a bash script tool, which contains `main.sh`, `common.sh`, `config.sh`. The `main.sh` used the commond `source` to load relative files.

I want to merge all files to **single** file for the convenience of distribution. Is there any best practice for that?

Comment: you can use your text editor, and replace the `source`d files with the contents of the listed file or you can write a script that does it for you. Depends on how much/often you expect to do that. And this will be flagged as an "opinion" question, which are off topic here. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: just rewrite your script and copy & paste everything in one single file? or you want to to something like *'head -n10 config.sh >> new.sh; head -n5 common.sh >> new.sh;*' to get just some lines of each script?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following script from: [Replacing 'source file' with its content, and expanding variables, in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531927/replacing-source-file-with-its-content-and-expanding-variables-in-bash)

It will "inline" the sourced file (referneced by '.' or by 'source' statement). It does not support calling source with parameters, locating files thru the PATH env var, etc. Hopefully, you do not need those features.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ (\.|source)\s+.+ ]]; then
        file="$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)"
        echo "$(cat $file)"
    else
      echo "$line"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.sh`, replace `source common.sh` with the contents of `common.sh` and `source config.sh` with the contents of `config.sh`. When you use the command `source`, Bash executes the content of the file passed as argument in the current shell (as opposed to a subshell). So, removing the code from other files and moving them into `main.sh` will have the same effect.

Read more about source: https://ss64.com/bash/source.html

Relevant superuser question: https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do